# node js receives wrong data from angular PUT call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm implementing a rest-crud  client in angular that sends data to a node api ( that I'm implementing as well )

When I try to send data from the form->angular to the node api with ngResource like so

```
  cmsApp.factory('Misc', ['$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/api/misc/:id', {}, {
          'update': { method:'PUT' } // the $resource obj comes with save/query/get/delete but lacks the update-put method
      });
  }]);
```

therefore I get an error

```
  Error: invalid json
```

now, I found a workaround following [this (old) article](http://cacodaemon.de/index.php?id=44)

```
 cmsApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function (data) {
          var str = [];
          for (var p in data) {
              data[p] !== undefined && str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[p]));
          }
          return str.join('&');
      };
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
  });
```

this trick kinda works but breaks all the strings in an array, so for example if I have a string like

```
 "foo bar"
```

what I get on the other side is

```
  {
    '0': 'f',
    '1': 'o',
    '2': 'o',
    '3': ' ',
    '4': 'b',
    '5': 'a',
    '6': 'r'
  }
```

that is clearly like unusable data.

I'd like to know the proper way to make this work, or if are any other correct pattern around, to make this right.

APPENDIX A

nodejs receiver code

```
    router.route('/misc/:misctype')
    .put(function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body.text_label);
    });
```

Comment: This is a classic example of the XY Problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.  It would be better to show the receiving server code and preferably the original JSON that is coming Invalid, rather than try to figure out why some other workaround isn't exactly right.

Comment: I we got the classic example of td;rd (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl%3Bdr) + "I think I know what's going on" here, fwiw I've embedded the code of the receiver

Comment: I read the whole document; You stated that you received "Error: invalid json", so you tried to implement a workaround you read somewhere which only partially solved the issue.  The thing is, if you included not just the receiving code but the actual output that was wrong, we could probably discover why it's coming across invalid without even needing to deal with that workaround that clearly was not written for your scenario to begin with.

Comment: The point is there isn't any reason why the first bit of code you posted would throw any error requiring a workaround, unless there is something else happening, and solving that is what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was related to the fact that I could have avoided all the mess with the

```
cmsApp.config(function ($httpProvider) { ..... }
```

part, and just set the object I was sending as json, because, firstly I had this

```
Misc.update({ id:'text_descr_assoc' }, $scope.description);
```

and by converting that in a json obj, and removing the now useless cmsApp.config part, everything worked out just fine

```
Misc.update({ id:'text_descr_assoc' }, {"my_key":$scope.description});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just send your data as a json? You are implementing both ends yourself, and using javascript in both. JSON is ideal for this use-case. For example in angular you would do something like:

```
// in some template (template.tpl.html)
<form>
  field
  <input name="name" ng-model="someObject.field"></input>
  other field
  <input name="email" ng-model="someObject.otherField"></input>
  <button ng-click="sendData">Submit</button>
</form>

//in the controller (myController.js)
$scope.someObject = {};
$scope.sendData = function () {
    doSomeValidation();
    $http.put('http://www.myservice.com/api/whatever', someObject)
    .success(function(result){
         console.log('it worked!'); 
     });
}
```

$http service knows to encode as JSON by default, and ng-model allows you to bind to form elements easily so there's no reason to bring a form library into it. And then in the node backend you'd just `JSON.parse(request.body)` or if you could use a middleware to do that if you are using Express.

for infos about the $http object you can look at the angular documentation on that topic [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: yes, but I would have avoided using raw $http and I'd had sticked to the $resource object from ngResource

Answer (score 0):

Try with a different content-type

```
"application/json;charset=utf-8"
```